# jQuery File Upload passing parameter

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

Html

```
<form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <!-- The global file processing state -->
            <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- The global progress state -->
        <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- The extended global progress state -->
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
</form>
```

Here Script

```
<tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td>
        <span class="preview"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
        <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="des"  class="form-control" placeholder="describe">
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="size">Processing...</p>
        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}
        {% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}
    </td>
</tr>
```

That my code.
    
        
    
I add this to get description for each photo.But I don't know how to keep it with another in json.I try

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
if (inputs.filter(function () {
        return !this.value && $(this).prop('required');
    }).first().focus().length) {
    data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    return false;
}
data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
console.log( inputs.serializeArray() );
```

But it not work.I don't know why.I try keep it in database but it have to ajax foreach to get the data.Now I try keep in json but I don't know how.Somebody help me please.
Thank you.

Comment: there is no `#fileupload` in your html.

Comment: Sorry I edit for you.